# group by week,month in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Learning `data.table` library. This is a reproducible example so I can use it on large datasets after understanding how this library works.

This is a dataframe.

```
dt = data.table(b=c('ford','honda','mercendes','ford','honda','mercendes'),
                co=c('blue','purple','yellow','bluef','purplef','yellowf'),
                mo=c(11230,13444,NaN,10000,10000,NaN),
                dates = c('2018-09-03','2018-09-03','2018-09-04','2018-09-04','2018-09-05','2018-09-05'))
```

I would like to do a group by date:
Normally would be done:

```
aggregate(dt$mo, by=list(dt$dates), sum)

     Group.1     x
1 2018-09-03 24674
2 2018-09-04   NaN
3 2018-09-05   NaN
```

But how to do it in data.table and if needed to show per day or per week or per month?

Comment: `month`, `week`, and `day` are all functions in data.table. You can use `by = list(month(dt$dates))`

Comment: Thanks people.Can you for this example make an answer? I tried reading the pdf but is kinda difficult. An example with this dataset  would make it simpler. Thanks

Comment: As exaple, you can try this `dt[, list(sum=sum(mo, na.rm = T)), by = list(month = month(dates))]`. (remove the `na.rm` option to have NAs).

Comment: great. Where can I find what else can I use instead of month? tried `day(dates)` but doesn't exist. for week exists. What else?

Comment: Type `?IDate` in console. All the dates related functions are listed there.

Answer (score 3):

Load your data

```
dt = data.table(b=c('ford','honda','mercendes','ford','honda','mercendes'),
                co=c('blue','purple','yellow','bluef','purplef','yellowf'),
                mo=c(11230,13444,NaN,10000,10000,NaN),
                dates = c('2018-09-03','2018-09-03','2018-09-04','2018-09-04','2018-09-05','2018-09-05'))
```

By week

```
dt[, .(count = .N), by = .(week = paste0(week(dates), "_", year(dates)))]

>       week count
> 1: 36_2018     6
```

By month

```
dt[, .(count = .N), by = .(month = paste0(month(dates), "_", year(dates)))]

>       month count
> 1: 9_2018     6
```

I would recommend to add "year(dates)" so that you can distinguish weeks/months from one year to another one.

Hope it helps